# How to reduce font size in bibliography so that it could be accomodated in less number of slides?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, fontsize

I have 9 slides containing references. How do i reduce the font size so that it could be reduced to 3 or 4 slides.
I am using this:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference}
    \begin{tiny}
            \printbibliography
    \end{tiny}
\end{frame}
```

Please suggest me to reduce the text size in bibliography or any other idea to accommodate it in 3 or 4 slides.

Comment: Please add a MWE. And after more than 10 questions, you might want to read [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192).

Comment: You could use `\fontsize{1pt}{1pt}\selectfont` for something that is smaller than tiny, but what's the point, no one is going to want to read that. May as well just say "full reference list in the paper available on request" in the slide and have the reference list elsewhere.

Comment: To quote the documentation: "beamer also introduces the two font sizes \Tiny and \TINY for really small text. But you should
know exactly what you are doing if you use them. You have been warned.". David is right: such a reference list is useless.

Comment: @samcarter everything working fine except bibliography font size. if you have any solution. please tell

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tiny and TINY are not working....when i used \begin{frame}[shrink=50, allowframebreaks]{Reference} , it appered two frames one empty and other with references. what should i do.

Comment: Maybe [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) can help you to improve your question.

Comment: "not working" is not a sensible problem description, but if I should guess I would say add \usepackage{lmodern}. Beside this: we already told you what you should do: Don't print such a long reference list in a presentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sir,, i tried one different solution which i found from texexchange: \def\bibfont{\tiny 5pt}, error appears: Command \bibfont already defined. ...ommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}` or `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\tiny}`, that's how you **re**define a command.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

The following is based on the code of another user who was kind enough to include a MWE in his question. So not sure if this works for you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```